# ausearch command and JAVA issue - RedHat 9

Tags: java, linux, spring, redhat, bufferedreader

I was triying to lunch some commands from JAVA to my RedHat server, this is the code that im testing:

```
  public synchronized String lunchLinuxCommand() {
        try {
            log.info("init lunchLinuxCommand");
            String[] cmdScript = new String[]{"/sbin/ausearch", "-ts", "today"};
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdScript);
            log.info("Command Executed");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            log.info("BufferedReader Created");
            String text = br.lines().collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
            p.waitFor();
            log.info ("text: " + text);
        } catch (Exception ex){
            log.error(ex.getMessage());
        }
        return " ";
    }
```

Im trying to run a **ausearch** command, to obtain audit information setted up correctly before, i was using different commands, different approaches to lunch the command like Process Builder, and some different ways to do the BufferedReader process, but the sistem do not respond. It just stocked, trying to wait for the command response, but after a lot time to wait it never respond.

[image]

I was testing with some other commands like pwd, ping or ls, and all of those are working fine.

I cannot understand why only with this one generates me an error, could someone please help me with that?

Thanks in advance.

Solve the issue trying to obtain audit info from REDHAT server

**[UPDATE]**

After **@g00se** approach, I continue having the issue testing from Intellij directly to the server via SSH, but in the server, part of the issue is solved, deploying the jar directly on it. Now, as you see in the next image, the p.waitFor() method its printing the response of the command in the LOG file and is not storing the response in the String variable.

[image]

I don’t understand why this behavior is coming up, and I was trying different approaches and orders on the code, without success. I feel is something related with Spring Framework or something that is generating the printing directly (as Sys.out) and don’t let me obtain that data.

Comment: Try instead `Process p = new ProcessBuilder(cmdScript).inheriIO().start();`, forgetting the `BufferedReader` reading for now. That's a privileged command btw, which will need to be run by root or used with sdo

Comment: Please post your *current* code to remove doubt. btw, my code can be simplified to `try (InputStream in = p.getInputStream()) { String text = new String(in.readAllBytes()); }`

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can get some output from the command as a normal user, so my comment above is not right. But the following works fine for me:

```
public synchronized String launchLinuxCommand() {
    try {
        log.info("init launchLinuxCommand");
        String[] cmdScript = new String[] { "/sbin/ausearch", "-ts", "today" };
        Process p = new ProcessBuilder(cmdScript).inheritIO().start();
        log.info("Command Executed");
        ByteArrayOutputStream bout = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        p.getInputStream().transferTo(bout);
        String text = new String(bout.toByteArray());
        p.waitFor();
        log.info("text: " + text);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        log.error(ex.getMessage());
    }
    return " ";
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response about it. I was testing from Intellij (From Windows 11 connecting the IDE with the RedHat server (SSH) and sending the deploy directly) and deploying the jar directly on the server. I continue having same issue on Itellij, but with your approach I was able to see the response of the command in the console. But I still having an issue. I see that the p.waitFor(); is lunching the response coming from the command and I cannot store it on variables. I update the case considering that.